# merge requests from gitorious.org to gitlab.com

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, gitorious

Our master repository was in gitorious.org. Now the master repository has moved to gitlab.com while the forks (or rather team forks) are still sitting in gitorious.org.

Now my query is how do I/we do merge/pull requests on gitlab.com when the repositories are in gitorious.org.

While I was able to change upstreams relatively easy using :-

```
$ git remote set-url
```

I was able to do the merge request process in gitorious.org which was just a button and putting description around the commit and that was that (in gitorious.org)

I know that all the people in the team would have to sign up to gitlab.com in order to push the button for merge requests but what else they would have to do ?

Update:- Based on Vonc's answer I think perhaps I was not clear.

This is where all the team repos are - on gitorious.org

```
~/games/shirishag75s-2014-mirror$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitorious.org:minidebconfindia/shirishag75s-2014-mirror.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitorious.org:minidebconfindia/shirishag75s-2014-mirror.git (push)
upstream    https://gitlab.com/debutsav/website14.git (fetch)
upstream    https://gitlab.com/debutsav/website14.git (push)
```

Now I know and see the button in gitlab for doing merge requests and this would work find IF all the other team repositories are in gitlab too. What if they are all in gitorious.org?

As far as I understand it, a merge request could be when you have made a single commit and want that to go to the main/original repository or a range of commits (a feature) which when you feel you are ready you ask for a merge/pull request. For this to happen 'easily' if both the repositories are using the same domain (either gitlab.com OR gitorious.org) then two competing services.

I would like to know if somebody is having the same scenario and how easy or hard it is to do the merge requests in such a scenario.

Comment: "What if they are all in gitorious.org": you need to have a mirror of that gitorious repo in GitLab in order to push a branch and initiate a GitLab merge request. That also means your devs have to be registered not just in Gitorious, but also in GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

All the users need to do is change their remote upstream url to the new team fork GitLab repo.

You can see the merge request illustrated in this [GitLab video (March 2014)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raXvuwet78M): it starts by working on an issue, creating a dedicated branch, which can then be the source of a merge request.
You see that "merge request" button in [this answer about GitLab workflow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/245915/3915).

Comment: I haven't seen the video but will see it in a few minutes. Thank you for sharing your wisdom.